# After Publish a webApp on IIS I'm getting "This site can’t be reached" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, publish

Whenever I try to publish my webApp on IIS manager I get following error on browser;

This site can’t be reached

192.168.1.114 took too long to respond.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I tried to get access my webApp on browser

This site can’t be reached

192.168.1.114 took too long to respond.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: A lot things can be wrong, so start from bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, It could be that your port is closed, please check your IP and Port in http://ping.eu/port-chk if its status is closed then this message will be shown, please open this Port.